# Connect to GeoNetwork from QGIS

Tags: qgis, metadata, geonetwork, csw

I want to connect my GeoNetwork catalog to QGIS by way of the CSW protocol (metasearch extension). The first step has been done in fact I have connected QGIS to GeoNetwork by copying this link http://localhost:8080/geonetwork/srv/en/csw?  and then the information of my catalog appear in the metasearch  windows.

**But the problem**  is when I try the search by map extent an error windows appears

```
Search error: 'Raised exception while searching metadata : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error when parsing spatial filter (version: 1.1.0):<ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
  <ogc:BBOX>
    <ogc:PropertyName>ows:BoundingBox</ogc:PropertyName>
    <gml311:Envelope xmlns:gml311="http://www.opengis.net/gml" srsName="urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84">
      <gml311:lowerCorner>-5 -4.5</gml311:lowerCorner>
      <gml311:upperCorner>29.5 30</gml311:upperCorner>
    </gml311:Envelope>
  </ogc:BBOX>
</ogc:Filter>. 
Error is: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parsing failed for Envelope: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not create crs: urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84'
```

Comment: Seems you are hit by https://github.com/geonetwork/core-geonetwork/issues/4072 . See also https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/337524/687