# Connection btw QGIS and GeoNetwork 3.6

Tags: qgis, metadata, geonetwork, csw

I am trying to connect my GeoNetwork to QGIS using the CSW protocol. The `GetCapabilities` request is OK.

But when I try to search some metadata this exception is raised:

```
Search error: 'Raised exception while searching metadata : 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error when parsing spatial filter (version: 1.1.0):
<ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
  <ogc:BBOX>
    <ogc:PropertyName>ows:BoundingBox</ogc:PropertyName>
    <gml311:Envelope xmlns:gml311="http://www.opengis.net/gml" srsName="urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84">
      <gml311:lowerCorner>-23 -90</gml311:lowerCorner>
      <gml311:upperCorner>23 90</gml311:upperCorner>
    </gml311:Envelope>
  </ogc:BBOX>
</ogc:Filter>. 

Error is: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parsing failed for Envelope: 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not create crs: urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84'
```

Comment: How are you doing the connection, what search are you doing?

Comment: It seems a problem in GN side trying to decode the `srsName` property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GeoNetwork 3.6 uses GeoTools 16.0. This version of GeoTools [doesn't support `urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84` CRS](https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/browse/GEOT-1710). The support for this CRS was introduced in GeoTools 17.1. GeoNetwork 3.8 still uses the GT 16 so the problem still exists in current GN release.

Issue in GN for tracking the problem: [#4072](https://github.com/geonetwork/core-geonetwork/issues/4072)

Comment: But If the GetCapabilities of the CSW service does not advertise that CRS, isn't QGIS at fault for requesting it?

Comment: AFAIK CSW GetCapabilities doesn't contain any reference to CRS names